# How do I solve a page-fault problem involving LRU, FIFO and Optimal page replacement algorithms?

Tags: page-fault

I was given this question:

**a** Given page reference strings: **1,2,3,4.2,1,5,6,2,1,2,3,7,6,3,2,1,2,3,6.**
Compare the number of page faults for **LRU, FIFO and Optimal** page replacement algorithms,
assume **4 frames** are available.
**b** Which method can you rank as the best and why?

I have tried solving it myself but keep getting stuck.

I even used tools like chatGPT and Gemini but they both kept giving contradicting values every time I regenerate the response.